# Regular Expression Pattern for list and td tag

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I am using a script which should read contents in `<li>` tag, please note that the `li tag` doesnt have any closing tag

```
<tr class="colors_background_main"> 
          <td colspan="2"> <li>Tools Color:blue
</td>
        </tr>
```

What i tried is to use the following regular experssion but it doesnt show any results

```
<li>\S*(.*)?</td>
```

**Classic ASP code to read the contents**

```
Set objRegExp = New RegExp

strPattern = "(?s)<li>\S*(.*?)</td>"


'<td[^>]*><p>.+?<\/p><\/td>"

objRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True

Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(strContents)

If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
    strTitle = colMatches(0).Value
Else
    strTitle = ""
End If

Set objRegExp = Nothing

Response.write(strTitle)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` does not match newline unless you use DOTALL mode.

Try following:

```
(?s)<li>\S*(.*?)</td>
```

This could not work unless your regular expression endigne supports DOTALL mode. In such case, use following regular expression:

```
<li>\S*([\s\S]*?)</td>
```

---

**NOTE**

The original regular expression will finish at the last . You should write `(.*?)` which is ungreedy, while yours `(.*)?` means optional. (Thank you @DioF)

Comment: That will finish at the last `</td>`. You should write `(.*?)` which is ungreedy, while yours `(.*)?` means optional.

Comment: Is it (?s) that i have to add before <li> ? As it throws an error when i add that

Comment: Which language/engine do you use?

Comment: @DioF I use Classic ASP Regexp

Comment: @user580950, Try the second regular expression.

Comment: @user580950 Just FYI: To say "I use Classic ASP Regexp" doesn't tell us what language you are using. Classic ASP is a framework that can use many different languages - typically either VBScript (looks like what you posted) or JScript (a MS variant of JavaScript), but it can also include Perl, Python, and many others depending on how you have the server set up. (admittedly very few are running Perl/Python/etc. but it exists)